# MEF Error when add item to list in constructor method

Tags: mef

i write silverlight program very simple.i use Mef and WCF.

this code  is MainPageViewModel class that included Commands and properties.

```
 public List<NoOfStudentsDropDownItem> ListNoOfStudent{get;set;}
 public MainPageViewModel()
 {
   InitializList();
 }
 private void InitializList()
 {
  ListNoOfStudent.Add(New NoOfStudentsDropDownItem(){DisplayText="1",NoOfStudent=-1});
  ListNoOfStudent.Add(New NoOfStudentsDropDownItem(){DisplayText="5",NoOfStudent=5});
 }
```

this is NoOfStudentsDropDownItem class;

```
public Class NoOfStudentsDropDownItem
{
   public string DisplayText{get;set;}
   public int NoofStudent{get;set} 
}
```

this is part of App Class.

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender,StartupEventArgs e)
{
  CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this);
  MainPage mainpage=new MainPage();
  mainpage.DataContext=MainViewModel;
  this.RootVisual=mainpage;
}
[Import]
public MainPageViewModel MainViewModel{get;set;}
```

i haven't error when commented InitializList method.i dont know cause.

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot to create the list. You declared a property for it, but it is never assigned so it will still be null when you call Add.